# Polygon will not display in angular / JavaScript layer

Tags: polygon, javascript, angular

I have allowed the user to draw a polygon and save the points to Firestore. When the page loads, Firebase retrieves the polygon coordinates relevant to a location. When I create the polygon rings using an array, the polygon will not display however when I hard code in the coordinates, it does display. This make me think it is not anything to do with the level the layer is being shown.

```
var polygon = {
          type: "polygon",
          rings: [
            vertices2

          ],
          spatialReference: { 'wkid': 3857 }
        };


        var polygon2 = {
          type: "polygon",
          rings: [[
            [-795810.8348419403, 7369902.643300892], //Longitude, latitude
            [-795800.449380898, 7369909.566947661], //Longitude, latitude
            [-795732.9438476748, 7369882.305107869], //Longitude, latitude
            [-795731.6456604884, 7369739.072207467],   //Longitude, latitude
            [-795806.0748404813, 7369741.66858184],  //Longitude, latitude
            [-795810.8348419403, 7369902.643300892]
          ]
          ],
          spatialReference: { 'wkid': 3857 }
        };
```

As you can see from the attached image, the console.log is displaying a comparison between the two polygons which to me look identical, so I cannot figure out why polygon2 will display and polygon will not.

[image: console.log screenshot]

Comment: Your "latitude" and "longitude" values aren't in the range {-90,+90} and {-180,+180}, and your SRID is  3857,  meaning the units are nominally "meters" (but aren't, really, since distance is meaningless in Web Mercator).

Comment: Why would the coordinates display when they are hard coded but not the same values as an array?